# @SpringBootTest - failed to load applicationcontext

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test, spring-junit, springjunit4classrunner

Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class FileInterfaceTest {
 @Test
 public void contextLoads() {
 }
```

}

Application :

AppConfig:

```
      @Configuration
      @ImportResource({ "classpath:process-flows.xml" })
      public class AppConfig {
               }
```

Have Bootstraploader class.

Error:

```
       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
       Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [file.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Resources loaction:

```
  src/main/resources
          ---process-flow.xml
          --- process.yml
  src/main/resources/env/cconfig
          --- file.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

Your folder structure contains a typo: `src/main/resources/env/cconfig` has to be `src/main/resources/env/config`

As defined in the [Spring Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files), `SpringApplication` loads properties from `application.properties` files in the following locations and adds them to the Spring Environment:

- A `/config` subdirectory of the current directory
- The current directory
- A classpath `/config` package
- The classpath root

Answer (score 0):

Apart from "cconfig" folder name (not sure if that was a typo) I also see your @ImportResource is mentioned as classpath:process-flows.xml however your resources folder has file named process-flow.xml

If that was not a typo as well, please add an 's' by renaming process-flow.xml to process-flows.xml and retry